# UndHandled Exception Has Occured

Tags: visual-studio

i have some problem with my visual studio this is some logcat from visual studio

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '30F105C9-681E-420b-A277-7C086EAD8A4E'.': 
DeviceException - Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.   Kelompok1       
Error       Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found. Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.    Kelompok1
```

then i have some clue in here

```
System.Exception
To install this application you need either a Windows developer license or a sideloading-enabled system.

Deployment of package App.a033e7614.afc07.a40e2.a80a7.aac85aa4b485c_1.0.0.0_x86_NorthAmerica_8wekyb3d8bbwe failed because no valid license or sideloading policy could be applied. A developer license (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=233074) or enterprise sideloading configuration (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231020) may be required.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and I solved it by enabling Developer Mode for my windows phone.

GOTO:

1. SETTINGS
2. Phone UPDATE AND SECURITY
3. FOR DEVELOPERS
4. SELECT DEVELOPER MODE. scroll down and:
5. Select MAKE your device visible to USB connections and your local network.

Hope this helps as it solved it for me and it will ask you to deploy the solution before running on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Had the issue again today and could not even see the phone in windows  explorer and this time the solution was that Visual Studio had an update that needed to be applied as well as the phone had an update ready to be installed.

Once both updated I could see the phone in windows explorer and was able to deploy the app to the phone.  Hope this helps.